# Not able to set default Angular uib-datepicker date to null / empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

The verion of Angular-bootstrap i'm using is **0.14.2**.

Issue: Though i set **ng-model to "" or null it sets to currentDate**. I want it to be empty. Cannot figure out what is the issue.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"
       datepicker-append-to-body="true" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"
       ng-model="businessJet.ExpirationDate"
       ng-change="info.updateRampFee(businessJet);"
       ng-click="businessJet.popupOpened = true"
       is-open="businessJet.popupOpened"
       ng-disabled="!businessJet.IsApplicable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the model to null will set the text to blank.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KjkZi814j36jAbEr3x3y

```
$scope.dateFormat = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy';

$scope.businessJet = {
    ExpirationDate:null,
    updateRampFee: function(dateObj) {
        console.log('date changed',dateObj)
    },
    popupOpened : false,
    IsApplicable : true
};

<input class="form-control" 
      type="text"
      datepicker-append-to-body="true" 
      uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"
      ng-model="businessJet.ExpirationDate"
      ng-change="businessJet.updateRampFee(businessJet);"
      ng-click="businessJet.popupOpened = true"
      is-open="businessJet.popupOpened"
      ng-disabled="!businessJet.IsApplicable" />
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, businessJet is an object of array. I'm setting for all the businessJet object ExpirationDate to null as you have done. It's not setting to empty on the view.
It works on Plunker. Not on my application. Weird behaviour.